# Switch to a branch without bringing changed code from another branch

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch named "improvement/02-improve-cart-page" but after doing some commits and changes to my code, I want to scrap this branch. As in delete the branch and go back to my develop branch which is my main branch.

I have the unchanged code in my "develop" branch and then the changed code in the "improvement/02-improve-cart-page" branch. When I do `git checkout develop`, the branch switches to develop but the code that was changed while I was in the "improvement/02-improve-cart-page" branch has remained.

What do I do so that I can go back to the "develop" branch code without any of the changes I made/committed? The "improvement/01-improve-cart-page" as well as the commits have not been pushed to Github

Upon doing `git reset --hard` while being in the develop branch, I get the following output  and the code has remained the same:
`HEAD is now at eae5c34 Merge pull request #6 from hudds-awp-cht2520/improvement/01-improve-products/page`

Comment: that is because you have _not_ committed the last changes since your last commit on `01-blahblah`. That is a git _feature_ (being able to switch into a different branch with uncommitted changes... there are some checks in place to avoid them from getting messed up). You can stash those changes if you think you might want to keep them for later (for ehatever reason) or you might just `git reset --hard` so that the changes that moved in the checkout go away for good (make sure not to have other things laying around in the worktree because they will be gone too when you run `git reset -hard`).

Comment: @eftshift0 please see my updated post, do I need to do `git reset --hard` in the `improvement/01-improve-cart-page` branch?

Comment: What does `git status` say, please?

Comment: @Schwern `On branch develop
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: @Dan So all your changes are committed? That suggests you merged improve-cart into develop. Can you show us `git log --graph --decorate --oneline develop improvement/01-improve-cart-page` Please edit it into your answer.

Comment: @Schwern I only committed all changes in the `improvement/01-improve-cart-page` branch. I have not merged improve-cart into develop

Comment: @Schwern I have edited my original post with the output, sorry.

Comment: eae5c34 is where improvement/01-improve-cart-page was merged into develop; you're going to see all the work from improvement/01-improve-cart-page in develop. improvement/02-improve-cart-page is branched off develop, so it will contain all the work in develop and  improvement/01-improve-cart-page.

Comment: @Schwern isn’t that the merge for the ‘improvement/01-improve-products/page’ branch with develop?

Comment: @Dan eae5c34 merges the changes *from* improvement/01-improve-cart-page *into* develop. Sorry, are we talking about a different branch now? In your question, sometimes it's 01 and sometimes its 02.

Comment: @Schwern I may be misunderstanding but this is what it mentions: `eae5c34 (origin/develop, develop) Merge pull request #6 from hudds-awp-cht2520/improvement/` Isn’t the `01-improve-products/page` merging with develop in eae5c34? Yeah I have just seen that I have made a mistake with the 01 and 02 in some of my posts, I’m really sorry for the misconfusion. 02 is supposed to be improve-cart-page

Comment: @Dan "*Isn’t the 01-improve-products/page merging with develop in eae5c34?*" "with" is slippery because it implies merging like two roads merging together into one. 01-improve-products/page is merging *into* develop, like the on ramp of a highway. Is the question now "why do changes in improvement/02-improve-cart-page still appear when you `git checkout develop`?" From your log that is not possible. Are you sure they are changes in improvement/02-improve-cart-page and not earlier? What does `git diff improvement/02-improve-cart-page develop` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250096/discussion-between-schwern-and-dan).

Answer (score 0):

> Upon doing git reset --hard while being in the develop branch,

You've achieved your goal. You discarded the unwanted changes and you are at the tip of the develop branch. You can confirm this with `git status`.*

(** - if you created new files while on `improvement/02-improve-cart-page` and not commited them then after `git reset --hard` you'll still have to remove them some other way (e.g. just deleting them in a file explorer)*)